# Using Call Method to Reference a Property in an Object - JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have the following object:

```
myObject = {
    color: "yellow",
    age: 23,
    nationality: "usa",
    getAge: function(){
        var age = 33;
        alert(age);
    }
}
```

I can call the `getAge()` method

```
myObject.getAge();
```

and I'll get 33 in the pop-up.

I'd like to get 23 in the alert box by changing the object *this* references.  I am thinking something like the following

```
myObject.getAge.call(this);
```

My understanding is that by passing *this* to the call method, I am changing the reference of *this* in the `getAge()` method to that of `myObject`, which then should allow the alert box to return 23.  Unfortuntaely, the result is still 33.

How do I change the *this* reference to that of `myObject`?

Comment: Without changing `getAge`, you simply can't. `age` will always reference the smallest possible scope, which will always be the local scope. Things are different when accessing `this.age` as Charlie Brown did in his answer -- this actually allows switching scope. But then the local variable `var age` won't work anymore.

Comment: _"How do I change the this reference to that of myObject?"_ - Your existing example with `myObject.getAge()` _already_ sets `this` to `myObject`. You need to change your function to use `this.age` rather than having a local variable in the function.

Answer (score 1):

```
myObject = {
    color: "yellow",
    age: 23,
    nationality: "usa",
    getAge: function(){
        alert(this.age);
    }
}
myObject.getAge();
```

You could be better off with a constructor, since *this* is getting mangled in there. See any other answer on SO on how `this` works.

```
function person(){
    this.color = "yellow";
    this.age = 23;
    this.nationality = "usa";
}
person.prototype.getAge = function(){
    alert(this.age);
};

var p = new person();
p.getAge();
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply:

```
myObject = {
    color: "yellow",
    age: 23,
    nationality: "usa"
}
myObject.getAge = function() { return myObject.age; };
```

Answer (score -1):

You could do it like this:

```
function getAge(){
  alert(this.age)
}

myObject = {
    color: "yellow",
    age: 23,
    nationality: "usa"
}

getAge(myObject) // Alerts undefined

getAge.call(myObject) // Alerts 23
```

This way you can use all kind of object that have an age property .

Here's a working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/P7nUU/1/), check browser console too

Comment: -1: syntax error, decoupling from the object is not needed to achieve this and because the undefined example makes no sense.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up with the syntax error. I don't encourage this method but its as close as I can think to what OP wanted